# Remap JSON object to other JSON structure

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to remap the following JSON structure that is formatted by categories and then per category can contain multiple locations. A location contains a lon/lat and an area code:

```js
{
  "cat1":[
    {"location":{
      "latitude":51.38,
      "longitude":4.34,
      "code":"0873"}
    },
    {"location":{
      "latitude":52.65,
      "longitude":6.74,
      "code":"0109"}
    },
    {"location":{
      "latitude":51.48,
      "longitude":4.33,
      "code":"0748"}
    },
    {"location":{
      "latitude":51.48,
      "longitude":4.33,
      "code":"0109"}
    }
  ],
  "cat2":[
    {"location":{
      "latitude":52.33,
      "longitude":4.32,
      "code":"0873"}
    },
    {"location":{
      "latitude":52.65,
      "longitude":6.74,
      "code":"0109"}
    },
    {"location":{
      "latitude":51.48,
      "longitude":4.33,
      "code":"0728"}
    }
  ],
  "cat3":[
    {"location":{
      "latitude":52.33,
      "longitude":4.32,
      "code":"0873"}
    },
    {"location":{
      "latitude":52.65,
      "longitude":6.74,
      "code":"0109"}
    },
    {"location":{
      "latitude":51.48,
      "longitude":4.33,
      "code":"0758"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Into the following structure, that is primarily focussed on the areacode, then has the categories with the actual locations in them.

```js
{
  "code":[
    {"0873":[
      {"cat1":[
        {"location":{"latitude":51.38,"longitude":4.34}}
      ]},
      {"cat2":[
        {"location":{"latitude":52.33,"longitude":4.32}}
      ]},
      {"cat3":[
        {"location":{"latitude":52.33,"longitude":4.32}}
      ]}
    ]},

    {"0109":[
      {"cat1":[
        {"location":{"latitude":52.65,"longitude":6.74}},
        {"location":{"latitude":51.48,"longitude":4.33}}
      ]},
      {"cat2":[
        {"location":{"latitude":52.65,"longitude":6.74}}
      ]},
      {"cat3":[
        {"location":{"latitude":52.65,"longitude":6.74}}
      ]}

    ]},
    {"0748":[
      {"cat1":[
        {"location":{"latitude":51.48,"longitude":4.33}}
      ]}
    ]},

    {"0728":[
      {"cat2":[
        {"location":{"latitude":51.48,"longitude":4.33}}
      ]}
    ]},
    {"0758":[
      {"cat3":[
        {"location":{"latitude":51.48,"longitude":4.33}}
      ]}
    ]}

  ]
}
```

I try to do this in Javascript/Node and was looking at a way to do this more elegant than traversing all objects by hand and restructure them.
Was looking into [reorient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reorient) and [obstruction](https://www.npmjs.com/package/obstruction) but can't find a way to get it done....

Any help is appreciated!

I know the pieces above are JSON strings that are read from file and then parsed to an object.

The code I have to do this is currently(its not finished, because I didn't know what would be the best way to do the `remapJson()`:

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

function remapJson(oldData) {
  var newData = {};

  // Do the convertion (loop all keys and values?)


  return newData
}

obj = jsonfile.readFileSync('oldstructure.json');

jsonfile.writeFileSync('newstructure.json', remapJson(obj));
```

Comment: you could add your code. please have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: I could suggest use  [javascript linq](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: I added some code and explainer on that I first parse the JSON-string to an Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for addressing the result arrays in a hash table.

```js
var data = { cat1: [{ location: { latitude: 51.38, longitude: 4.34, code: "0873" } }, { location: { latitude: 52.65, longitude: 6.74, code: "0109" } }, { location: { latitude: 51.48, longitude: 4.33, code: "0748" } }, { location: { latitude: 51.48, longitude: 4.33, code: "0109" } }], cat2: [{ location: { latitude: 52.33, longitude: 4.32, code: "0873" } }, { location: { latitude: 52.65, longitude: 6.74, code: "0109" } }, { location: { latitude: 51.48, longitude: 4.33, code: "0728" } }], cat3: [{ location: { latitude: 52.33, longitude: 4.32, code: "0873" } }, { location: { latitude: 52.65, longitude: 6.74, code: "0109" } }, { location: { latitude: 51.48, longitude: 4.33, code: "0758" } }] },
    result = { code: [] };

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
    data[key].forEach(function (a) {
        [a.location.code, key].reduce(function (r, k) {
            var o = {};
            if (!r[k]) {
                r[k] = { _: [] };
                o[k] = r[k]._;
                r._.push(o);
            }
            return r[k];
        }, this)._.push({ location: { latitude: a.location.latitude, longitude: a.location.longitude } });
    }, this);
}, { _: result.code });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: On the code-snippet it indeed works flawlessly Thanks!
On importing the json file and parsing it though, it errors out with a 
`data[key].forEach(function (a) {
                ^
TypeError: data[key].forEach is not a function
    at Object.keys.forEach._ (/Users/mwesten/source/tekenradar/temp.js:30:17)
    at Array.forEach (native)`

[The file used to import from](http://f.dlmax.org/y2016-gm/y2016-gm.json)

Comment: @Max, you could check `data[key]` with `Array.isArray(data[key])` first, it it is array.

Comment: Thanks ;) that fixed it !

Comment: Still seems to miss a lot... original json file posted above is 473KB and the resulting json file is 84KB while the structure isn't changed that much... Will try to count how much I'm missing, but I think the array-check cuts the loop off too early. json posted above is welformed, so that isn't the problem...

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
var a = //your json
var newArray = [];
for(var i in a){
    var obj = {};
    var newobj = {};
    var innerobj = {};
    var locationobj = {};
    if(a[i].length != 0){
        var keyname = i;
        for(var j = 0;j<a[i].length ; j++){
            if(a[i][j].location.code == "0873"){
                locationobj["latitude"] = a[i][j].location.latitude;
                locationobj["longitude"] = a[i][j].location.longitude;
                innerobj[i] = {"loaction":locationobj};
                obj[a[i][j].location.code] = innerobj;
                newArray.push({"code":obj})
            }else if(a[i][j].location.code == "0758"){
                locationobj["latitude"] = a[i][j].location.latitude;
                locationobj["longitude"] = a[i][j].location.longitude;
                innerobj[i] = {"loaction":locationobj};
                obj[a[i][j].location.code] = innerobj;
                newArray.push({"code":obj})
            }else if(a[i][j].location.code == "0109"){
                locationobj["latitude"] = a[i][j].location.latitude;
                locationobj["longitude"] = a[i][j].location.longitude;
                innerobj[i] = {"loaction":locationobj};
                obj[a[i][j].location.code] = innerobj;
                newArray.push({"code":obj})
            }

        }
    }
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Can you give a version which does not hard-wire the area codes?

Comment: it would be difficult because code is inside of loop and for fetching that you must iterate it...

Comment: Hmmm the area codes are dynamic (they are found by matching the location-data (lon/lat) against a topoJSON file containing the area-codes that are written to that location. Afterwards I need to reorder the stuff to be able to create a [Choropleth](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) of that data, so I don't know the area-codes upfront....

Comment: taking all codes into array and then iteration will make trick