# Compare and transform the array object by comparing two object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, group-by

I have the below object

```js
[{
    "ad_id": "60002985",
    "value": [{
        "name": "hi Datta",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "2345678900",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "1234567890"
      },
      {
        "name": "hello hari",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "1234567890",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "2345678900"
      },
      {
        "name": "hi Datta",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "2345678900",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "9876543210"
      },
      {
        "name": "hello ravi",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "9876543210",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "2345678900"
      },
      {
        "name": "how good you are",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "2345678900",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "1234567890"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ad_id": "60002990",
    "value": [{
        "name": "Hi Datta",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "2345678900",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "3423423422"
      },
      {
        "name": "Hello ashok",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "3423423422",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "2345678900"
      }
    ]
  }
]]
```

there will be a common value for every object list it will be either from "Sent_to_mobile" or "Sent_from_mobile" in every object. here common value for this example object is '2345678900'.
 
 I just need to group out the values in array objects which has "Sent_to_mobile" and "Sent_from_mobile" has same values and their reply messages ie. Sent_to_mobile should be equal with another object Sent_from_mobile.

it has transformed like below object

```
 [
  {
    "ad_id": "60002985",
    "0": [
      {
        "name": "hi Datta",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "2345678900",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "1234567890"
      },{
        "name": "hello hari",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "1234567890",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "2345678900"
      },
      {
        "name": "how good you are",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "2345678900",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "1234567890"
      }
    ],
    "1":[{
        "name": "hi Datta",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "2345678900",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "9876543210"
      },
      {
        "name": "hello ravi",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "9876543210",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "2345678900"
      }]
  },
  {
    "ad_id": "60002990",
    "0": [
      {
        "name": "Hi Datta",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "2345678900",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "3423423422"
      },
      {
        "name": "Hello ashok",
        "Sent_to_mobile": "3423423422",
        "Sent_from_mobile": "2345678900"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a helpful script to transform an object

Comment: there is no pre-made script anywhere for that, the solution is to create the new array from inside a loop

Comment: for yours I'd remember the 2 mobiles and match every object with them, removing matching object from original array at the same time, then go on with new mobile pair ...

Comment: @mplungjan you can't mark it as duplicate, maybe related but (almost) every question asking to remap a json is unique

Comment: here you go : https://jsfiddle.net/jrezmnbt/2/

Comment: @jonatjano thanks for the solution

Comment: @jonatjano SO is not an elance site. All the tools necessary to do the job are shown in the dupe which is one of 100 dupes. There are reduces and pushes etc. I can post more dupes if you wish.

Comment: @mplungjan I've done this one firstly because the two number thingy interested me, I know we cant do that for every question but some has things I never tried before and I like them. Then since I had the answer might as well give it

Comment: @jonatjano Go ahead and answer. It is just encouraging people to ask "gimme teh codez" type questions - The dupe I posted is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675953/remap-json-object-to-other-json-structure